# Duplicate NETCDF data values across timesteps using R

Tags: r, duplicates, time-series, netcdf, cdo-climate

I have `6-hourly` data and will like to '`duplicate`' it to `hourly` data.

The first 6-hour timestep starts on `2017-01-01 00:00:00` and the next 6-hour timestep starts on `2017-01-01 06:00:00`. I would like to copy the value of `2017-01-01 00:00:00` and assign it to the next `5 time steps` and so on ...

The outpout should follow this pattern (illustration only):

```
Date       Time     Value
2017-01-01 00:00:00 0.00012120
2017-01-01 01:00:00 0.00012120
2017-01-01 02:00:00 0.00012120
2017-01-01 03:00:00 0.00012120
2017-01-01 04:00:00 0.00012120
2017-01-01 05:00:00 0.00012120

.
.
.

2019-12-01 00:00:00 0.0024270
2019-12-01 01:00:00 0.0024270
2019-12-01 02:00:00 0.0024270
2019-12-01 03:00:00 0.0024270
2019-12-01 04:00:00 0.0024270
2019-12-01 05:00:00 0.0024270

.
.
.
```

Do the same for the next 6-hour timestep which is 2017-01-01 06:00:00 in the attached file.

Assume that the hourly rainfall remains constant during the 6h period. Thus, each hour in the 6h period has the same rainfall value.

Sample NETCDF data are found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w3Mzd9A2qSdBBAmt3WxBBo64A8zrw5pn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You probably need to use `shifttime,1hour` etc to create datasets to merge. Then use `mergetime` to get the final dataset.

Comment: @RobertWilson. Can you throw more light on your suggestion using the sample file? Thank you. I want to get hourly data from 6h data by duplicating 6h values across the next 5 timesteps etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create 5 NetCDF files with the time shifted by 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 hours:

```
cdo -shifttime,1hour testing.nc testing1.nc
cdo -shifttime,2hour testing.nc testing2.nc
cdo -shifttime,3hour testing.nc testing3.nc
cdo -shifttime,4hour testing.nc testing4.nc
cdo -shifttime,5hour testing.nc testing5.nc
```

Then merge them using mergetime:

```
cdo mergetime testing*.nc out.nc
```

Comment: what a smart solution:) Thank youvery much.